# ошибка консоли in transformraise MissingRequiredArgument(param)

Tags: python, бот

Пишу бота, вылезает ошибка при выполнении команды `.info`. С предыдущей командой `.test` все работало хорошо, но как только пишешь .инфо, так в консоли ошибка. Имеется ввиду выполнение исполнение команды в дискорде
вот, что отвечает консоль -

```
 File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: arg is a required argument that is missing.
```

А это уже сам бот.

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
import os, sqlite3

bot = commands.Bot( command_prefix = ".", intents = discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))

    global base, cur
    base = sqlite3.connect('firstpr.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('DataBase connected - OK')

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Да, я тут')

@bot.command()
async def инфо(ctx, arg = None):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if arg == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Введите:\n.инфо общая\n.инфо команды')
    elif arg == 'общая':
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Я - фроппи бот и слежу за порядком в чате!')
    elif arg == 'команды':
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} .test - Проверить, онлайн ли я\n .статус - мои предупреждения')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Такой команды не существует...')


bot.run(
```

Comment: У вас `info` в коде написан по-русски(`инфо`) или так задуманно?

Comment: да, так и задумано

Comment: пробовал и на англ, ничего. тоже самое

Comment: @Tehnorobot, как то так..

Comment: Напишите вместо `arg = None` вот это: `arg: discord.Member = None`

Comment: @Tehnorobot, нет, не помогло. То же самое отображение в консоли

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так, возможно поможет.

```
@bot.command(aliases=['инфо']) # Теперь команда будет срабатывать и на .info, и на .инфо
async def info(ctx, arg:str=None):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if arg is None:
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Введите:\n.инфо общая\n.инфо команды')
    elif arg == 'общая':
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Я - фроппи бот и слежу за порядком в чате!')
    elif arg == 'команды':
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} .test - Проверить, онлайн ли я\n .статус - мои предупреждения')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{author.mention} Такой команды не существует...')
```